# How to stop background image from scrolling any further past certain depth?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make background image follow scroll until it reaches certain depth (offSetHeight of a certain div), and past that I'm trying to make it stay in certain position. Here are some photos to explain it a bit better:

[image]

[image: As we keep scrolling down, we can see background image going past div.]

I've tried doing it in JavaScript, but to no avail as the picture just gets stretched and I can't manage to hit stop when bottom of background image hits upper part of div.

```
window.onscroll = function() {onScroll()};

function onScroll() {

    let scrollHeight = document.body.scrollTop;
    
    let element = document.getElementById("learnMorePt2IdStandard"); // div where image should stop
    let elementHeight = element.offsetHeight;
    console.log("Element height: " + elementHeight + "\nCurrent height: " + scrollHeight);

    if(scrollHeight <= elementHeight){
        document.body.style.backgroundAttachment = "";
    } else {
        document.body.style.backgroundAttachment = "local";
        document.body.style.backgroundSize  = "auto"
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = rgb(254,220,50); // cover all other parts of background that image won't cover (rgb function is defined and works as intended)
        // document.body.style.objectFit = "cover";
    }
}
```

I've tried trying different types of background-attachment properties as well as objectFit, but to no avail.

If problem is in background image I can always try to re-edit it but I think it could be done with JavaScript somehow using *background-attachment* property in CSS.
Please let me know if I can explain it any further. Thank you!

EDIT:
Here is where I'm trying to get background-image to stop. If user wants to continue scrolling past, picture should stay in place, and as user scrolls down, "the hand" would go above viewing area, and not follow scroll and "hide" behind gray div.
[image]

Comment: `window.onscroll = function() {onScroll()};` <-- Why are you doing it like that? Use a _passive_ `addEventListener` otherwise you'll wreck UX: https://web.dev/uses-passive-event-listeners/

Comment: `document.body.style.backgroundColor = rgb(254,220,50);` <-- this won't work: all `.style` properties must be `string` values (unless `rgb` is a `function` you've defined that generates a valid CSS color string?), I assume you simply forgot to add quotes around it, so it should be `document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(254,220,50)";`

Comment: It might be useful if you included a proper code snippet to show it in action, I am having a bit of trouble understanding what exactly you are trying to do. Are you trying to have the hand image stop at the end of the element with the "Pravite [...] ili noviji"?

Comment: @Dai Thank you for your comment. I haven't given that much thought, but I'll change it to Event Listener. Didn't know there's differences. Also, rgb function is defined in code but I didn't put it in as I didn't think it was necessary for this problem, and it works as intended.

Comment: @Aurange Thans for the comment. I'm edited my question by adding additional image that I've photoshopped to make it look like what I'm trying to do. Hope this clears it out.

Comment: The css sticky element will work to avoid having to use any JQuery or JS. There is an example on codepen.io (https://codepen.io/SamA74/pen/vxrPOp). If you provide the relevant HTML and CSS, I could take a look.

I noticed that this solution doesn't appear to function on a Mac using Safari, though functions well on Chrome. You can read about compatibility for css sticky [here][1]

  [1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position